# SQLite is not available error on pkcs7.Decrypt() of MimeKit

Tags: c#, pkcs#7, mimekit

I've encountered an error `SQLite is not available` while decrypting a mime message after executing `pkcs7.Decrypt()`. Please see my block of code below:

```cs
public MimeEntity decryptMessage(MimeMessage message)
{
    // Putting the value of message.body to a string for checking only
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        responseString.Body.WriteTo(memory);
        string bodystring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memory.ToArray());
    }

    var pkcs7 = message.Body as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;
    if (pkcs7 != null && pkcs7.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData)
    {
        // the top-level MIME part of the message is encrypted using S/MIME
        return pkcs7.Decrypt();
    }
    else
    {
        // the top-level MIME part is not encrypted
        return message.Body;
    }
}
```

I've tried to put the value of `message.Body` into a variable and check its value but it seems that it doesn't have any problem:

```
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data;
    name=smime.p7m
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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```

So now I can't understand why the error says `SQLite is not available` despite that I'm not using any database connection on this one. I'm new to using MimeKit. If anyone knows how can I do this it will be a great help.

Comment: Can you show the error's traceback too, not just the error message?

Comment: https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/issues/33